# When does Magento decrement quantity

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I'm looking for the exact point in the codebase where Magento decreases the quantity of a product after payment. I have noticed that it happens after payment authorize and not capture, if I am correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento is `decreasing /increasing`  the quality using basically event observer on class  `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock`.There lot event code is written there which in call at config.xml.Just see config.xml of Mage_CatalogInventory

### Events:

```
    <sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>
        <observers>
            <inventory>
                <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                <method>checkQuoteItemQty</method>
            </inventory>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>
    <checkout_submit_all_after>
        <observers>
            <inventory>
                <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                <method>checkoutAllSubmitAfter</method>
            </inventory>
        </observers>
    </checkout_submit_all_after>
    <sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
        <observers>
            <inventory>
                <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                <method>subtractQuoteInventory</method>
            </inventory>
        </observers>
    </sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
    <sales_model_service_quote_submit_success>
        <observers>
            <inventory>
                <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                <method>reindexQuoteInventory</method>
            </inventory>
        </observers>
    </sales_model_service_quote_submit_success>
    <sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure>
        <observers>
            <inventory>
                <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                <method>revertQuoteInventory</method>
            </inventory>
        </observers>
    </sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure>
    <sales_order_item_cancel>
        <observers>
            <inventory>
                <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                <method>cancelOrderItem</method>
            </inventory>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_item_cancel>
    <sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
        <observers>
            <inventory>
                <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                <method>refundOrderInventory</method>
            </inventory>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
```

and as schmengler said the

class `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock`  responsive for that cases.

On Class [`Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/053e0b286cbd6d52ac69ca9fd53a3b72c78aca1d/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php) function

**subtractQuoteInventory**() decrement the stock depends  on  `getInventoryProcessed()` flag value  which Sales quote Object element.

On  order place order Magento fire `checkout_submit_all_after` and s`ales_model_service_quote_submit_before`  event which is called observer `[cataloginventory/observe -checkoutAllSubmitAfter]`.

If those event is not fire then it not possible reduce stock qty.

On this class  function `revertQuoteInventory()` revert quantity when quote `is failed to convert to order [sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure]`
 and `Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->revertProductsSale($items);`

Answer (score 7):

It actually happens after placing the order, independent of the payment method.

The responsible code is in [Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/053e0b286cbd6d52ac69ca9fd53a3b72c78aca1d/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock.php#L133-154)