# Decrease stock when order status changes to processing

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I have a condition that I have to change/decrease the stock only when the order status changes to processing. By default it is changed as soon as order is placed. But, this is what I need to achieve.

Comment: have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to find the controller/model that decreases the value, but I am unable to find it. By the way, plan is to override that particular file and then create custom event to fire an observer for that order status change and then in that observer , decrease the quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,read the question [When does Magento decrement quantity](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58462/when-does-magento-decrement-quantity)

**Let do some tricky code this requirement.**

First,in order to stop **decrement**  rewrite the Observer class[`Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/053e0b286cbd6d52ac69ca9fd53a3b72c78aca1d/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php#L603).

At this class add this code for revert the stock which  just decrease.

```
$items = $this->_getProductsQty($quote->getAllItems());
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->revertProductsSale($items);
```

Then using `sales_order_save_after` with checking order status  process you can deducted the stock

Comment: what has to be done in `sales_order_save_after` ?