# Function used for decreasing product inventory qty from admin

Tags: product, admin, inventory

Can anyone help me for Which function is used for subtracting product inventory when order is placed from backend admin side?

Comment: its default behavior of magento

Comment: I understand. But there might be any function in core file which is being used for decreasing product qty. I want to override that function. @GopalPatel

Answer (score 2):

Check function `subtractQty`

> app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php

```
public function subtractQty($qty)
{
    if ($this->canSubtractQty()) {
        $this->setQty($this->getQty()-$qty);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On Class `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer` function

`subtractQuoteInventory()` **decrement the stock** depends on `getInventoryProcessed()` flag value which Sales quote Object element.

Helpful links : [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/58469/45103)