# Stock reduction on Invoice instead of Order

Tags: orders, invoice, stock, inventory

Currently, **stock gets reduced when the Order has been placed**, is there any way to change on `invoice?`

As there, lot of junk orders, is there any way to make stock reducing when invoice for the corresponding stock has been made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stock reduction is done in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer` . So to do it first we will have to stop quantity decrement. To do this go to method `public function subtractQuoteInventory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){}` in your rewritten observer and add below code

```
$items = $this->_getProductsQty($quote->getAllItems());
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->revertProductsSale($items);
```

Now you will have to hook event `sales_order_save_after` and in that observer you may reduce the stock

[When does Magento decrement quantity](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58462/when-does-magento-decrement-quantity) This will help you in case you want to understand the decrement process

Answer (score 2):

By default `Magento` provides this configuration for decrease stock from `store > config > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options` (Magento 2) , for Magento 1 `system > config > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options`

`Decrease Stock When Order is Placed`. You can set this option to `No` If you do not want to decrease the stock on order place.

[image]

And to decrease the stock on Invoice you can use event `sales_order_invoice_save_after`.

Comment: thanks, there is sequence of other steps which needs to be handled in code to achieve it. It will be good if magento team does as configuration.

Comment: yes, there are number of steps to achieve your complete requirement,  butI thought this may give some light  :) @arvindwill

Comment: yes it gave the direction and achieved , thanks.

Comment: Accept the answer If you find it helpful @arvindwill