# M2 decrease inventory account on processing only

Tags: magento2.2.2, inventory

Right now our inventory is decreased even for pending orders (which never get's paid for), and you get the low stock emails when it goes below 1.
Is there any way to only decrease item stock qty when the customer for paid (processing) orders?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest don't implement that option that will cause you over booking / over sold items issue ( whenever there is any high traffic or on sale ). However if you still want to do this review this link , hope it will work for you :

[Stock reduction on Invoice instead of Order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194704/stock-reduction-on-invoice-instead-of-order)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Naveed, over sold isn't much of an issue in this case, but I see your point. 
Was some useful info on that link, that points me in the right direction.