# Magento 2 Decrease stock when invoice is placed

Tags: magento2, stock

I want change product stock when invoice is placed, not change when order is placed. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

By default Magento provides this configuration for decrease stock from `store > config > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options` (Magento 2)

And to decrease the stock on Invoice you can use event `sales_order_invoice_save_after.`

Answer (score 0):

Stock reduction is done in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer` . So to do it first we will have to stop quantity decrement. To do this go to method public `function subtractQuoteInventory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){}` in your rewritten observer and add below code

```
$items = $this->_getProductsQty($quote->getAllItems());
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->revertProductsSale($items);
```

Now you will have to hook event `sales_order_save_after` and in that observer you may reduce the stock
[When does Magento decrement quantity](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58462/when-does-magento-decrement-quantity) This will help you in case you want to understand the decrement process

Comment: Thank you, but this is magento 1, i want decrease stock when invoice is placed on magento 2